# Using mockito is there a reason to nullify mocks in @After?

Tags: mockito

I'm wondering,

If in @Before method I'm initializing a mock objects, shouldn't I nullify references to it in @After ? Or would that be redundant? And why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Not necessary**, JUnit creates a new instance of the test per test method.

However if it's static fields it's another story, and proper lifecycle should be implemented, but I strongly advise you to not use static fields in a JUnit test ! Instead think about implementing your own JUnit Runner.

And for TestNG, it's a different story, as TestNG creates a single instance of the test, so you have to be careful there on the lifecycle of the mocks.

Comment: Even if the field is static - the @Before method will reinitialize the mocks, so what's the problem with static methods here. Unless they are static final (constant) it should work fine (but who would do such a thing). Also even if JUnit would not create a new instance of test class each time - what does it change here?

Comment: Good remarks about mocks! My comment was not really related to mockito, but more general to the lifecycle of statics, eg spring contexts, or whatever

Answer (score 0):

"Nullifying" reference doesn't change anything here.

`@Before` annotated method is ran before each test method. If you are initializing mocks in such method they will be reinitialized before each test. There is a different annotation - `@BeforeClass`, this annotation causes a method to be executed only once before execution of any test method in that test class. In this case however "nullifying" a reference will not help you because you still need to create a new mock object and assign its reference to your field.